# 100 000 вопросов в свободной базе знаний!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Спешу поздравить сообщество с прохождением отметки в

## 100 000 вопросов!

[image: 100 000 вопросов]

Поздравляю, коллеги!

За каждым вопросом стоит реальный человек, с настоящей проблемой. Согласно данным [обозревателя данных Stack Exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/) вопросы были заданы 23 000 различных разработчиков. Все эти люди в трудный момент доверились сообществу, как одному из лучших источников знаний в Рунете.

**Спасибо всем знатокам, которые каждый день приходят на сайт, чтобы помочь коллегам своими знаниями. Без вас это было бы невозможно!**

Уверен, 100 000 – это только начало!

Comment: В честь такого события надо стрелять в воздух.  Из низкоорбитальной ионной пушки, например.

Comment: @Nofate Можно претвориться, что именно для нас завтра в 12 будет выстрел на Петропавловской. :)

Comment: Ура, товарищи! А можно ссылку на запрос, дабы лично лицезреть сию прелестную цифру, которая, я уверен, уже выросла? И что за баннер справа? Самореклама?

Comment: @Other Количество вопросов можно посмотреть в [боковой панели сверху](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions). Уникальных авторов я считал так: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OwnerUserId) FROM Posts Where PostTypeId = 1;`. Баннеры – [реклама сообщества](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/6). Надеюсь я правильно понял ваши вопросы!

Comment: Количество я не нашёл, а Ваш запрос мне вывел `22991` http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/516072 Зато узнал про баннеры, идея интересная, благодарю; выросли ли показатели после ввода этих... призывов?

Comment: @Other Пока еще данных нет. В следствии небольших конверсий, чтобы действительно понять, что происходит, необходим время. Я планирую в конце августа посмотреть на цифры.

Comment: @Other Верным курсом идём, товарищи!

Comment: @Other цифру можно видеть тут http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday если наведете мышью на количество вопросов в строке Stack Overflow на русском - в hint-подсказке отобразится точное значение.

Comment: @cheops, благодарю, запрятано что-то, зато уже +376 вопросов со вчера. Неплохо, я бы сказал.

Comment: @Other Извиняюсь, не увидел ваш вопрос. Скорее всего, вы не видите цифру так как у вас выбрана не та сортировка. Чтобы увидеть количество вопросов, необходимо перейти в раздел «[Вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions)», и выбрать сортировку «[новые](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, странно, ибо проглядел я. Вижу теперь что растём мы как на дрожжах, +511 за два дня!

Comment: Коллеги, браво. Стоя апплодирую. Особенно тем, кто мне помог. Полагаю, миллион через пять лет осилим.