# Итоги 2016 года

Tags: поддержка, итоги-года

2016 год выдался богатым на достижения:

- Мы создали прекрасные [баннеры](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/), мотивирующие наших коллег принять участие в создании базы знаний. Спасибо [@andreycha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/), [@МстиславПавлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179652/), [@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/), [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/), [@EllaSvetlaya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179703).
- Перешагнули через рубеж в [100 000 вопросов в нашей базе знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/)! Уху!
- Сначала [обогнали Super User](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/) по количеству вопросов в день, а затем и вовсе [заняли третью позицию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4160/) среди всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange!
- Значительно улучшили перевод сайта, за что отдельное спасибо [нашему шеф–переводчику @alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4066/).
- [Репутация @VladD перевалила за 100 000!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd)

А еще теперь у нас есть [справка в видео формате](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4191/)!

Хорошо, что с цифрами? Где цифры!?

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | на русском         |  на русском       |
|                    | 2015 год           |  2016 год         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Задано вопросов   |     24 596         |    52 714         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|Опубликовано ответов|     33 648         |    56 221         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Новых участников  |     16 290         |    28 980         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|     Уникальных     |     3 400 000      |    5 345 000      |
|     посетителей    |                    |                   |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|   Просмотренных    |     13 700 000     |    26 150 000     |
|      страниц       |                    |                   |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Как видно из таблицы выше, наше сообщество шаг за шагом движется к тому, чтобы стать лучшим сообществом русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения в Интернете. На мой взгляд, главными предпосылкой к этому является желание наших коллег задавать профессиональные вопросы именно на Stack Overflow на русском. Это не случайно, ведь фундаментом тому служит:

- Наша культура. Мы не критикуем и не оцениваем авторов, мы не отсылаем к поисковикам. Мы стараемся помочь, используя, по возможности, *все* правила русского языка. Мы глубоко уважаем и тепло относимся друг к другу.
- Реальная помощь. Мы действительно помогаем нашим коллегам. На сайте нет разговоров за жизнь.
- Свободная база знаний. Помощь одному участнику становится «заметкой» в формате проблема–решение, без лишнего ненужного шума, которой в будущем будут пользоваться многие сотни и тысячи наших коллег!
- Сообщество – мы с вами (да-да)! Каждый, кто приходит задать вопрос, видит увлеченных профессией людей, среди которых хочется быть.

Знания, опыт и добродетели, собравшиеся в сообществе людей, дают нам, сообществу, уникальную возможность возвести наш [Город Знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146/) здесь и сейчас. Для этого сообществу нужна именно ваши помощь и поддержка в наступающем, 2017 году. Помощь может быть разной:

- отвечайте на вопросы ваших коллег;
- [задавайте ваши вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/);
- [модерируйте сообщество](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4209/);
- и конечно же, *рекомендуйте сайт друзьям и коллегам*!

Вместе мы сможем построить наш русскоязычный островок знаний.

#### Спешу поздравить всех участников и пользователей Stack Overflow на русском с наступающим Новым годом и пожелать всего наилучшего!

Будем рады видеть вас в новом году! Нас всех ждет много всего интересного!

<sub>[Лучший подарок от вас, о котором может только мечтать компания, – ваше мнение о сайте и рекомендации о его дальнейшем развитии. Пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв о Stack Overflow!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4317/)</sub>

Comment: А вот **5345000** уникальных посетителей (рост в 1.5 раза) действительно впечатляет (надеюсь, это не боты -)). Значит и в самом деле мы в сети нужны. / ***С наступающим НГ, успехов во всем!***